# How to fix "Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:" Android Studio - Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I first install flutter with the help of documentation in official Flutter site. And also set up Android studio as IDE for a flutter. After that steps guided to create a new flutter project and run on emulator/actual device on the boiler-plate code of the application for count number of button press by the user. But it threw unhandled exception every time.

I have tried running on emulator and actual also but all threw errors only. If anybody has some knowledge of flutter please help me as I am new to flutter environment. Refer code for more information.

```
//**********************main.dart**************************
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

/// same as boilerplate code in any flutter new app
///My Flutter Version - *****************************************
Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (6 weeks ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
Engine • revision 52c7a1e849
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.765], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.1)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:


// Error on run app
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
--------- beginning of main
06-10 10:49:33.781 D/VvmStatusSmsFetcher( 1919): Request SMS successfully sent
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:360:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:289:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:513:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:688:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:318:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:361:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:389:23)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:449:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:819:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:447:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:383:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:301:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: The flutter doctor says that you're using an outdated version of Flutter, plus it says that you haven't installed the Flutter extension in Visual Studio Code. Try addressing those issues first.

Comment: I have just downloaded the flutter from the official website ( how it can be outdated from the flutter official site) and Sir do we need to install plugins for VS code if I am only using Android Studio as IDE for Flutter.

Comment: My mistake, you are on the stable channel not the beta or dev. I would personally suggest you use VScode as your Flutter IDE.

Comment: There's a known problem with the new update of Android Studio; since you've installed the new version, you're facing this "Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:"
I've provided a temporary solution below; please, check that.

Flutter team knows about this problem already; but they can't say when it would be officially solved, yet!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > > Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

This problem is with the new update of Android Studio (29)

There is a temporary fix for now (if you're using Windows)!

**1.** Close Android Studio

**2.** Open CMD and write:  `taskkill /f /im adb.exe`

**3.** Download this file: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

**4.** Go to

> C:\Users[your-username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

and replace the "platform-tools" folder with the new one that you just downloaded.

ps: (a) don't forget to keep the backup (b) the AppData is a hidden folder (you may not see it at first)

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend. You saved me.